# Is it safe to catch general Exception in non crucial action?

Tags: php, symfony

After sending order by customer, application sends notification email to admin. If latter fails, I don't want to bother customer with error page. Just log error.

in controller:

```
try {
    $mailer->sendToAdmin('New order', $body);
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    $logger->log($e);
}
```

Is it safe to catch \Throwable here? If not what are example problems it could cause?

Comment: Only problem could be if there's something further down the script which relies on the result of the function which crashed. But it doesn't look like that would happen in this case. Your question is phrased as an opinion/discussion question though, which is off-topic here. If you ask something more concrete about observable behaviour in the code, rather than whether it's "good" or "appropriate" (which are both subjective terms) then it would be more likely to be on-topic. See also [ask] and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Its always "safe" to catch `Throwable` because thats what try-catch is supposed to do.
Basically its a business decision and in your case you have to ask yourself if you want to deny service to a client when your internal business processes dont work as intended based on how much those will affect the client. In your case it does not affect the client much (if at all)